# Determine Static files based off route or domain in ASP.NET Core for SPA

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, routes, single-page-application

Is it possible to return different static files based off the route in ASP.NET Core 2 / 3 + ?

For example:

`app.domain.com` would render some `index.html` for a public SPA (ReactJS / VueJS)

`admin.domain.com` would render some other `index.html` for a private authenticated SPA (Angular)

`www.domain.com` would render a third `index.html` for the public landing page

I couldn't find how in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For return different content based on domain, you could try to change the content in `UseStaticFiles` like

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    OnPrepareResponse = async ctx =>
    {
        var request = ctx.Context.Request;
        string index = "";
        if (request.Host.Host.Equals("app.domain.com") && request.Path.Value.Contains("index.html"))
        {
            index = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
                "wwwroot", "PublicIndex.html");
        }
        else if (request.Host.Host.Equals("admin.domain.com") && request.Path.Value.Contains("index.html"))
        {
            index = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
                "wwwroot", "PrivateIndex.html");
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(index))
        {
            var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(index);
            ctx.Context.Response.ContentLength = fileBytes.Length;
            using (var stream = ctx.Context.Response.Body)
            {
                await stream.WriteAsync(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
                await stream.FlushAsync();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Make sure there is a default index.html in the `wwwroot` folder.

Answer (score 2):

You could always try a custom file provider:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddOptions<StaticFileOptions>()
            .Configure<IHttpContextAccessor, IWebHostEnvironment>(
                delegate(StaticFileOptions options, IHttpContextAccessor httpContext, IWebHostEnvironment env)
                {
                    options.FileProvider = new ClientAppFileProvider (httpContext, env);
                }
            );

    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles();
    }
}

public class ClientAppFileProvider : IFileProvider
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;

    public ClientAppFileProvider(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        _env = env;
    }

    public IDirectoryContents GetDirectoryContents(string subpath)
    {
        return _env.WebRootFileProvider.GetDirectoryContents(subpath); ;
    } // End Function GetDirectoryContents 


    public IFileInfo GetFileInfo(string subpath)
    {
        string host = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Host.Host;
        if (host.Equals("app.domain.com"))
        {
            subpath = Path.Combine("app", subpath);
        }
        else if (host.Equals("admin.domain.com"))
        {
            subpath = Path.Combine("admin", subpath);
        }
        else if (host.Equals("www.domain.com"))
        {
            subpath = Path.Combine("www", subpath);
        }

        // return _env.ContentRootFileProvider.GetFileInfo(subpath);
        return _env.WebRootFileProvider.GetFileInfo(subpath);
    }


    public IChangeToken Watch(string filter)
    {
        return _env.WebRootFileProvider.Watch(filter);
    } // End Function Watch 


}
```

Comment: Great idea ! Thank you very much for that code ! While it was only half-finished and didn't compile, I got the idea and managed to get it to work. As a public serice, I fixed the bugs in your sample code. Compiles now. Also, Path.Combine won't work under this circumstances. Instead, do string subpath2 = subpath.StartsWith("/") ? subpath : "/" + subpath;
                    subpath2 = "/" + host + subpath2;